# How come the subject is omitted in Spanish?

Tags: etimología

You can find hundreds of sources where they say that the subject can be dropped if it doesn't add any additional information. As "voy" is the 1st person singular conjugation of "ir", you know that the subject is "yo". That sounds reasonable when coming from the English language, where conjugation is basically missing.

Well, but my mother-tongue is German and in German we do decline verbs as well. As "gehe" is the 1st person singular conjugation of "gehen", the subject is "ich". But in German you generally don't omit the subject.
And that's true for other languages, too. French, for instance. As "vais" is the 1st person singular conjugation of "aller", the subject is "je".

So, how come that Spanish language has developed in a different way?

Comment: My theory (supported by no actual evidence that I've found, but to me it seems logical) is that it has to do with ambiguity. In German, many of the different "types" of subjects share a single form. In French, you pronounce about one letter in each word :), so you can't really tell the difference between the forms. I realize this theory might not hold up when talking about other languages about which I really don't know, but it just seems logical to me. So pro-drop languages tend to have distinct forms for each subject.

Comment: @Aprendedor I am not sure if I understand you. What do you mean here by subject? The grammatical subject as I refer to in my question. In that case, there's no difference between German and Spanish. I mean in both languages they are distinct. With one exception in German ("sie"). Or was it a typo and you wanted to say verb form (conjugation)? But then there is ambiguity in both languages. For instance, Spanish "yo/él estaba", German "wir/sie sind".

Comment: I meant that the subjects share a single *verb* form. And even though there is indeed ambiguity in both languages with regard to this, in German, there seems to be "more" ambiguity. "Wir" and "sie" always share the same form, but "ich" and "er" often share the same form as well. "Yo" and "él" do share the same form in some cases (like the imperfect, subjunctive, and conditional), but it is still not in every form.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lovely question!

The conjugation of a verb in Spanish has more info about the person: in German *sie, Sie* und *wir* are conjugated the same way, and here is the key: they **always** coincide. Also in the singular, the verb for some personal pronouns very often coincide (*ich muss*, *er muss*). So you do need a personal pronoun in German. And well, in English, as you say, for obvious reasons you cannot drop it.

As for French, you do write different, but phonetically there is no distinction between *(tu) vas* and *il va* (unless you have some vowel right after). This holds not only for *aller*.

So, basically, my hypothesis is that since in Spanish from Spain in most of the verbs in various tenses the conjugation fully determines the person, there is no need to keep track of it. Then, although in some versions of Latinamerican Spanish *ustedes* is used instead of *vosotros* and the former has the same conjugation of *ellos*, dropping the pronoun was inherited.

You basically economize without loosing information. There is no information redundancy. (Nice feature, isn't it? [1]) To support the statement, there is (at least) another language which, to some extent, does the same: Russian. There conjugation is so irregular, that you might omit the pronoun. (Example: *знать* in present is conjugated as *знаю, знаешь, знает, знаем, знаете, знают.* The forms are all different)

However, you might want to keep the personal pronoun if you want to emphasize the person. Dropping the person would be like in Dutch choosing *je* as a personal pronoun and saying the pronoun would be choosing *jij*.

*Late Edit*: I just realized there is a name for those languages: [pro-drop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro-drop_language).

---

[1] I think the German analogous of "no information redundancy" –although departing from verbs and I'm unsure if that was how it developed– would be that in the *schwache Deklination* of adjectives you kind of drop lots of their endings, for the determinate article already has them:

> *ein netter Kumpel* Vs. *der nette Kumpel* (← you no longer need to write *netter*, for *der* is already saying that the noun is masculine, while *ein* doesn't)

Comment: There is some truth in what you say, but things are not so simple. In Japanese, for example, they don't have declension and omit the subject even more than in Spanish. There is no confusion and everything is inferred from context. So declension is just one factor, not the whole answer.

Comment: Portuguese often drops the subject as well. The conjugation in Portuguese is very similar (in many verb/tense combinations, identical) to Spanish, so the same reasoning would follow.

Comment: @Flimzy yes, well, I didn't dare to write that, because I don't speak Portuguese. But it's mentioned in the article as *pro-drop* language.

Comment: Mh, at least the speakers of Russian I know rarely (if ever) drop the pronoun. I even asked them about this once and they said it sounds strange if you do. Maybe it varies across the country.

Comment: @GregorBruns I'm not so sure of that: "как тебя зовут?" –quite likely the first sentence in any Russian course– is already a pronoun omission. I don't mean Russian always omits the pronoun (neither does Spanish!). But I'm more or less convinced that it's not rare practice.

Comment: @c.p. Right, drop the (if ever). Although your example is more a "passive" or impersonal thing like "Me llaman el Zorro". I guess what I wanted to say is that Russian sentences often include the pronoun (at least in my experience) while the last mails in Spanish I got contained no subject pronoun whatsoever. Therefore we require more explanations for the pro-drop phenomenon than simply distinguishable inflection. Still, +1 for a very good start.

Comment: @c.p. Correct me if I'm wrong. But in "как тебя зовут" *тебя* is the pronoun but what they often drop is the verb *to be* as in "вы очень красивый" (oups, don't know how to inflect, Krasivaja I guess^^).

Comment: @Em1 Well, in  "как тебя зовут?" "тебя" is indeed a pronoun, but it's in accusative, that is, there still a pronoun omission. The question without it would be: "как тебя зовут *они*?" (*wie nennen dich?* Vs. *Wie nennen sie dich?*) And you are right, the *to be* verb is omitted (for the present tense). So that's precisely why you are not unable to omit the pronoun there: there is not even a verb to inflect! "очень красивая" или  "очень красивый" would incorrect forms for a second person as вы (may you do say "очень красивая" when the context is clear)

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know Latin also allow to drop the subject: v.g. *cogito ergo sum* does not have an explicit subject *ego*.

So the question might be backwards: why other Latin-derived languages such as French require the subject?  In Italian, Catalan or Galician you can drop it.  In Portuguese you cannot (yet Portuguese and Galician are almost the same language.)

As Spanish has verbal declination by person, it reduces ambiguity compared to English, but that's only part of the answer.  Spanish just evolved that way while English had a different evolutive path.

French had added ambiguity in verb declinations given its phonetics, and this is partly solved by forcing the subject's pronoun, but some linguists actually see that French “subject pronouns” are really part of the declination.  Compare:

> *Je vais au cinéma.*
>   *Moi, Je vais au cinéma.*

With Spanish:

> *Voy al cine.*
>   *Yo voy al cine.*

The actual explicit subject in spoken French is *moi*, while *je vais* is the first person declination, although in writing it still behaves as *je* being the subject and *vais* being the declination. (and *moi* being just an emphatic repetition.)

This phenomenon is replicated in some Francoitalic dialects such as Piedmontese, but it does not explain why Galician keeps the dropping of subjects, while Portuguese does not.

Which leads to the actual answer: **that's how each language is.**

Comment: Portuguese does often drop the subject as well. See [here](http://www.learningportuguese.co.uk/language/subject-pronouns.html) and [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1059710).